# How do I project 3D shapes onto the screen in cases where part(s) of the mesh falls behind the "eye" of the perspective projection matrix?

Tags: c, graphics, 3d

Here, I am trying to draw a grid of lines in 3D space (the triangle marks the origin). I use cglm functions to create my perspective projection matrix, as well as a view matrix. The problem is that every vertex with a position behind the camera position (eye) is projected onto the screen in an unexpected location such that I can't just draw the line from vertex to vertex and cull whatever's behind the near plane.
[image: actual output]
I have a general guess as to what's happening, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Here's the necessary code:

```
// draw grid
Color line_color = { 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 1.0f };
for (float i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
    vec3 h1 = { -25.0f, 0.0f, -25.0f + i};
    vec3 h2 = {  25.0f, 0.0f, -25.0f + i};
    draw_line(scene->image, h1, h2, line_color);
    vec3 v1 = { -25.0f + i, 0.0f, -25.0f};
    vec3 v2 = { -25.0f + i, 0.0f,  25.0f};
    draw_line(scene->image, v1, v2, line_color);
}
```

```
void draw_line(Image* img, vec3 v1, vec3 v2, Color color) {
    ivec2 p1; ndc_to_pixel_space(img, v1, p1);
    ivec2 p2; ndc_to_pixel_space(img, v2, p2);
    int dx = p2[0] - p1[0];
    int dy = p2[1] - p1[1];
    if (dx == 0 && dy == 0) {
        if (0 <= p1[0] && p1[0] < img->width && 0 <= p1[1] && p1[1] < img->height)
            put_pixel(img, (int)p1[0], (int)p1[1], color);
        return;
    }

    if (abs(dx) > abs(dy)) {
        // draw line from left to right
        if (p1[0] > p2[0]) {
            ivec2 tmp = { p1[0], p1[1] };
            p1[0] = p2[0]; p1[1] = p2[1];
            p2[0] = tmp[0]; p2[1] = tmp[1];
        }
        // cull line out of view
        if (p1[0] > img->width) return;
        if (p2[0] < 0) return;
        
        int x = p1[0] < 0 ? 0 : p1[0];
        for (; x <= p2[0]; x++) {
            if (x > img->width - 1) break;
            int y = (dy * (x - p1[0]) / dx) + p1[1];
            if (0 <= y && y < img->height)
                put_pixel(img, x, y, color);
        }
    }
    else {
        // draw line from bottom to top
        if (p1[1] > p2[1]) {
            ivec2 tmp = { p1[0], p1[1] };
            p1[0] = p2[0]; p1[1] = p2[1];
            p2[0] = tmp[0]; p2[1] = tmp[1];
        }
        // cull line out of view
        if (p1[1] > img->height - 1) return;
        if (p2[1] < 0) return;

        int y = p1[1] < 0 ? 0 : p1[1];
        for (; y <= p2[1]; y++) {
            if (y > img->height) break;
            int x = (dx * (y - p1[1]) / dy) + p1[0];
            if (0 <= x && x < img->height)
                put_pixel(img, x, y, color);
        }
    }
}
```

```
void ndc_to_pixel_space(Image* img, vec3 src, ivec2 dest) {
    vec3 proj;
    mat4 p; glm_perspective(45.0f, (float)img->width / img->height, 0.001f, 100.0f, p);
    mat4 v; glm_lookat((vec3){0.0f, 2.0f, -5.0f}, (vec3){0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f}, (vec3){0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}, v);
    mat4 mvp; glm_mat4_mul(p, v, mvp);
    vec4 vp = { 0.0f, 0.0f, (float)img->width, (float)img->height };
    glm_project(src, mvp, vp, proj);
    dest[0] = (int)proj[0];
    dest[1] = (int)proj[1];
}
```

I've tried flipping values and changing component values of each vertex position before and after they've been projected, but to no avail. This is what my expected output is:
[image: expected output]